# How to Combine Vertices and edges into one In Unity

Tags: c#, camera, lag

I'm new to Unity and I'm making a car racing Game. Now, I'm stuck at some point. I was looking for some solution of my problem, but couldn't succeed.

My problem is:

1. When I run my game on my phone, it sticks badly because whenever there are several buildings in front of the car camera, like one building behind another building, it lags. Reason for this is there are so many vertices and edges at that time, So the Car Camera is unable to capture all that stuff at same time.
2. How do I preload the 2nd Scene while loading 1st Scene?

I am using Unity free version.

Answer (score 0):

In graphics programming, there is a common routine to simply don't draw objects that aren't in the field of view. I'm sure Unity can handle this. Check link: [Unity description on this topic](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OptimizingGraphicsPerformance.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not hugely knowledgeable about Unity, but as a 3D modeller there's a bunch of things you can do to improve performance:

1. Create a simplified version of your buildings with fewer polygons for use when buildings are a long way away. A skyscraper, for example, can be as simple as a textured box.
2. If you've done that already, reduce the distance at which the simpler imposters are substituted for the complex versions.
3. Reduce the number of polygons by other means. A good example is if you've got a window ledge sticking out of the side of a building, don't try and make it an extension of the body. Instead, make it a separate box, delete the facet that won't be seen, and move it to intersect with the rest of the building.
4. Another good trick is to use bump maps or normal maps to approximate smaller features, rather than trying to model everything.
5. Opaqueness. Try not to have transparent windows in your buildings. It's computationally cheaper to make them just reflect the skybox or a suitably blurred reflection imposter. Also make sure that the material's shader is in Opaque mode, if it supports this.
6. You might also benefit a little from checking the 'Static' box on the game object, assuming that buildings aren't able to be moved (i.e. by smashing through them in a bulldozer).
7. Collision detection can also be a big drain. Be sure to use the simplest possible detection mesh you can - either a box, cylinder, sphere or a combination.